# "Your position" or "their position"

Tags: listening

On this [audio file](http://79.175.174.232/content/lessons/12/Intermediate2_2/unit_6/listening/listening.mp3), at 1:25, shouldn't it be `their position`?

Source: The ILI English Series, Intermediate 2, Page 87

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either *their* or *your*.

*Their* refers directly to the headlights' position.

*Your position* means *the position that your headlights are in*. It is *your position* because they are *your car's headlights*.

It is like someone talking about your mobile phone and saying *your memory is full* (which equals *the memory on your mobile phone is full*). You could also say *its memory is full.*